# Is a server farm abstracted on both sides?

Tags: web-farm

I am trying to understand how a solution will behave if deployed in a server farm. We have a Java web application which will talk to an FTP server for file uploads and downloads.

It is also desirable to protect the FTP server with a firewall, such that it will allow incoming traffic only from the web server.

AT the moment since we do not have a server farm, all requests to the FTP server come from the same IP (web server IP) making it possible to add a simple rule in the firewall. However, if the application is moved to a server farm, then I do not know which machine in the farm will make a request to the FTP server.

Just like the farm is hidden behind a facade for it's clients, is it hidden behind a facade for the services it might invoke, so that regardless of which machine from the farm makes the request to the FTP server, it always sees the same IP?

Are all server farms implemented the same way, or would this behavior depend on the type of server farm? I am thinking of using Amazon Elastic CLoud.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends very much on how your web cluster is configured.  If your cluster is behind a NAT firewall, then yes, all outgoing connections will appear to come from the same address.  Otherwise, the IP addresses will be different, but they'll almost certainly all be in a fairly small range of addresses, and you should be able to add that range to the firewall's exclude list, or even just list the IP address of each machine individually.

Answer (score 1):

Usually you can enter cnames or subnets when setting up firewall rules, which would simplify the maintenance of them. You can also send all traffic through a load balancer or proxy.  Thats essentially how any cloud/cluster/farm service works.

many client ips <-> load balancer <-> many servers